# Generic deep cloning with depth limitation in tree hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm using Code First development with Entity Framework. The problem is:
while cloning lazy loaded list, list elements are type of:

`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Node_CB2936E7A8389F56009639CD3D732E4B509C4467531A6AFB3A143429D77A07DF`

and my generic function see it as `System.Object`. Is there any way to cast this object to they parent class, before they are pass to `Clone` function? Or other ideas?

Because  I need clone only to specific depth, I can't serialize whole tree structure and then deserialize it.

My model is:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual IList<Node> Nodes { get; set; } 

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And function use to clone:

```
protected T Clone<T>(T entity, int depth) where T : new()
{
    var cloned = new T();
    foreach (var property in cloned.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" && property.CanWrite)
        {
            property.SetValue(cloned, property.GetValue(entity));
        }
        else if (depth > 0 && property.CanWrite)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic")
            {
                var type = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
                var collection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
                var value = property.GetValue(entity);
                foreach (var element in value as IEnumerable)
                {
                    collection.Add(Clone(element, depth - 1));  // here is Error:
                        //The value “System.Object” is not of type “Sandbox.Models.Node” and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value
                        //I should cast element to its parent class but how?
                }
                property.SetValue(cloned, collection);
            }
        }
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

This function works perfect on non-Entity Framework objects.
And usage of `Clone` function is:

```
var cloned = Clone(context.Nodes.Find(10), 2);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is `var` in your foreach loop will be of type `Object` so `new T();` on your inner call to `Clone` will be performing a `new Object()` and not a `new WhateverTheTypeTheListHad()`. What you need to do is make that new call using reflection also.

```
protected T Clone<T>(T entity, int depth) where T : new()
{
    return (T)CloneInternal(entity, depth);
}

private object CloneInternal(object entity, int depth)
{
    var cloned = Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType());

    foreach (var property in cloned.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" && property.CanWrite)
        {
            property.SetValue(cloned, property.GetValue(entity));
        }
        else if (depth > 0 && property.CanWrite)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic")
            {
                var type = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
                var collection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
                var value = property.GetValue(entity);
                foreach (var element in value as IEnumerable)
                {
                    collection.Add(CloneInternal(element, depth - 1));
                }
                property.SetValue(cloned, collection);
            }
        }
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

Because the recursive calls have no dependency on knowing the type being passed I prefer to split the logic up and make the recursive internal version non generic and just pass down Object. It makes it more obvious when you have false assumptions (like calling `new` on `Object`).

However, your code has other problems. For example you do the inner recursion on any type that is in `System.Collections.Generic` but you always create a `List<genericListType>`, had the collection been something else (for example a `HashSet<genericListType>`, very common in EF) your code will fail on the `property.SetValue(cloned, collection);` call.

Here is a quick rewrite to handle anything that implments `IList`, `IList<T>` and `ISet<T>` (and has a default constructor), that should cover 90% of all the collections you will encounter.

```
    private object CloneInternal(object entity, int depth)
    {
        var cloned = Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType());

        foreach (var property in cloned.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (propertyType.Namespace == "System" && property.CanWrite)
            {
                property.SetValue(cloned, property.GetValue(entity));
            }
            else if (depth > 0 && property.CanWrite && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
            {
                if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
                {
                    var collection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
                    var value = property.GetValue(entity);
                    foreach (var element in value as IEnumerable)
                    {
                        collection.Add(CloneInternal(element, depth - 1));
                    }
                    property.SetValue(cloned, collection);
                }
                else if (propertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var type = propertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                    if (typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(type).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType) ||
                        typeof(ISet<>).MakeGenericType(type).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
                    {
                        var collection = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
                        var addMethod = collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
                        var value = property.GetValue(entity);
                        foreach (var element in value as IEnumerable)
                        {
                            addMethod.Invoke(collection, new[] {CloneInternal(element, depth - 1)});
                        }
                        property.SetValue(cloned, collection);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cloned;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear and helpful explanation. It works like a charm. And thank you for pointing other problems.

Comment: @py3r3str I added a update showing how to fix the collection issue, it could be made more robust but it gives you a start.

Comment: Nice. Thank once again.